# loading static files inside a css file in Django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a css file and i want to import another css file inside it. 
How can I do this in Django ?

This is my style.css file and I want to import owl.carousel.css in it.

```
@import url("owl.carousel.css");

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #34495E;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
```

I am using {% load static %} on my template to link style.css but how can import a css inside a css ?

```
<link href="{% static "assets/css/style.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to import a `.css` file inside a `.css` you will need to use the path, as usual.

```
@import url('/path/to/your/file.css')
```

If they are in static folder:

```
static/styles/file1.css
static/styles/file2.css

/* in file2.css */
@import url('file1.css')
```

It is not possible to use the django template language inside a `.css` file.

Comment: It looks like you can use the django templates in any file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225412/6655092

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HTML style and script tags to load something inside your static files.

```
<style>
    @import url("{% static 'path/to/your/file.css')")
</style>
```