# How to provide image path in "main.css" in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to build an app in Django, I have created a home page, the statics paths I have set for the project working fine. I am able to render HTML(**index.html**) associated CSS (**main.css**) and images perfectly except an image "banner.jpg".

For other images, I have set path as we usually do in Django,

```
<img src="{% static 'images/image1.jpg' %}" alt="" />
```

For the banner of the home page, I tried to set a path in CSS something like given below.

**main.css**

```
#banner {
        background-color: #e5474b;
        color: #f2a3a5;
        padding: 13em 0 11em 0;
        background-color: #0c0c0c;
        background-image: url("../images/banner.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 15% left;
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
```

or

```
#banner {
    background-color: #e5474b;
    color: #f2a3a5;
    padding: 13em 0 11em 0;
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    background-image: url("{% static 'images/banner.jpg' %}");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 15% left;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

but both the methods never work, however when I set path "url("../images/banner.jpg")" without Django it works perfectly and renders the image in the background. Where should I make the changes to correct this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: try: `background-image: url("/static/images/banner.jpg");`

Comment: .css file is static file which means it does not render tags as jinja template

Comment: You could also use an inclusion_tag to dynamically build and then include in the template css styling. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

Comment: @Ben its not working :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144698/use-django-template-syntax-in-a-css-file

Comment: This is hacky, but you could start with the full url for your image, `http://localhost:8000/static/images/banner.jpg` make sure that works, then start chopping off the front until you find it.

Comment: I am able to fix the problem by a quick hack I don't know technically how correct it is but it worked for me. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling and reviewing the comments,  I am able to find a quick fix that works perfectly for me.

```
<head>
  ...
  <style>
    #banner {
      background-image: url("{% static 'images/banner.jpg' %}");
    }
  </style>
 ...
</head>
```

I just cut past the background-image section from "main.css" to "index.html" under the header section and it works perfectly.